# WebSockets and a proxy

Tags: c#, html, proxy, websocket

I have started implementing web sockets using [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck),

Now the office has a proxy which seems to be causing some issues:

---

**1)** Connecting to my local IP (192.168.21.80) with all proxy settings off:

```
Request URL:ws://192.168.21.80:8181/value
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
```

the socket connects and everything is happy.

---

**2)** Connecting to my local IP (192.168.21.80) with "Automatically detect settings" checked.

```
 Request URL:ws://192.168.21.80:8181/value
 Request Method:GET
 Status Code:Success
```

This is still also the same if "Bypass proxy server for local addresses" is checked.

However if I uncheck "Automatically detect settings" and only check "Use a proxy server for your LAN..." and add an exclusion of my IP it all works happily again.

Now the problem I have with this is our proxy script for automatic detection actually sets an exclusion for IP of "192.168.21.*"

**Has anyone seen this before or know why the proxy causes sockets to behave this way?**

Comment: Just guessing, but there is probably a proxy filter on protocols.  Have you checked with your network admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the proxy we are using **BlueCoat** doesn't support WebSockets for the good old reason of "security" or the such

Even when going to my local address and the proxy gets in the way and prevents the use of sockets. Obviously if I bypass local addresses this will work except on (Automatically Detect)

Comment: did you find out which proxy server was used?